# Arduino for Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: arduino-yun

I want to create a Wi-Fi hotspot and redirect all connections to a custom login page.

I would like to know if the Arduino Yún is a good choice in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Better use a regular router and flash DD-WRT or OpenWRT to it (check the supported router list on their websites). Next use something like NoCatSplash, to create a captive portal with login.

<strike>Arduino's just are not fast enough for this.</strike> Arduino Yuns are typically more expensive.

Comment: Did you know that operating system the Yun runs is OpenWRT?  It's no slower or faster than most home routers since it uses the very same chip that many of them do.

Comment: Thank's ! I have also read Raspberry PI could be a good choice ?

Comment: Mikrotik has some really nice routers / switches that will be able to do what you want for a very reasonable price and fairly good performances.

Comment: Raspberry + SD card + power adapter + usb-wifi module. So more expensive than a typical router. Also since both wifi and ethernet go over usb on the Pi, the maximum speed is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project where I make a Yun into a hotspot and even have it act like a captive portal so users can control things though the Yun...

http://wp.josh.com/2014/05/01/a-platform-for-casual-encounters-with-interactive-technology/

Even though it does work, I can not recommend using the Yun for something like this unless you have no other choice. It is just not a good platform and you end up wasting huge amounts of time on unnecessary problems.

Much better to use something like a BeagleBone or Raspberry PI to handle to Wifi stuff. You can then connect these to a normal Arduino if necessary to deal with your hardware.

Comment: So how to have a hotspot (like mikrotik)
and also control hardware using raspberry pi? What is the server I can use? @bigjosh